# Getting the column letter to change but keep the row number constant within excel macro using vba

Tags: excel, vba

so I created this stock estimator sheet within excel that has two macros that use VBA. The whole idea of the sheet in the first place is to type in a portfolio of stocks, (one ticker per cell, going horizontally at the top of sheet1, then using the macros develop in this workbook that helps me analyze the stocks i have entered.

the first macro uses a query, scrubs data off of yahoo finance and market watch (per ticker), and dumps it all into one sheet. From there i have a a couple sheets that reference that summary sheet, giving me the data that i want to get.

The second macro creates individual sheets for each ticker. it first uses a template that i have created within excel (just a couple of charts and other data points) and copies and pastes that into a new sheet. Next it copies and paste a range from one of my reference sheets (All ticker analysis) and pastes the data points into that template to populate the charts.

The issue that i am having is not being able to get the range from the reference sheet to change. To be more specific, in this line of code Sheets"("All Ticker Analysis").range("B2:B34").Copy", i need the B2:b34 to change to c2:c34 to d2:d34 etc until all of the tickers are ran through the code.

please let me know if anyone has an idea on how to solve my issue :)

Thanks!

my code for the macro is below

```
Sub IndividualSheets()

For i = 2 To Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).column

Dim a As String

'Assigning the variable a the Ticker we are running through the loop

a = Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value
Sheets.Add before:=Sheets("Zack's Data Daily Update Data")

'Renaming the new sheet the current ticker that is going through the loop

ActiveSheet.Name = a

'copying the template of the individual sheet into a new sheet with the ticker that is going throught the loop

Sheets("Template").range("A1:O86").Copy
Sheets(a).Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
CutCopyMode = False

'copying the data from the "All ticker Analysis" sheet into the individual sheet for the ticker that is going through the loop


Sheets("All Ticker Analysis").range("B2:B34").Copy
Sheets(a).Select
Cells(2, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
CutCopyMode = False

Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
range("A1:A500").EntireRow.RowHeight = 15


Next i


Sheets("All Ticker Analysis").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Cells` and the column index.

Comment: Hey BigBen, thanks for your comment! i appreciate your time. i will look into this and see if i can get this to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (untested)

```vb
Sub IndividualSheets()

    Dim rng As Range, a As String, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, wsATA As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsATA = wb.Sheets("All Ticker Analysis")
    
    Set rng = wsATA.Range("B2:B34") 'first column to be copied

    For i = 2 To wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
        Set ws = Sheets.Add(before:=wb.Sheets("Zack's Data Daily Update Data"))
        ws.Name = Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value
        Debug.Print "Created sheet '" & ws.Name & "'" 
        
        wb.Sheets("Template").Range("A1:O86").Copy ws.Range("a1")
        Debug.Print "Pasted template range to '" & ws.Name & "'"
    
        rng.Copy ws.Range("B2")
        Debug.Print "Copied " & rng.address(0,0) & " from  " & _
                    rng.Parent.Name & " to B2 on " & ws.name
        
        ws.Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
        ws.Range("A1:A500").EntireRow.RowHeight = 15
    
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1) 'next column over for copy source
    Next i
    
    wsATA.Activate
    wsATA.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim. i appreciate your response and time with this. Your code is a lot more efficient than mine. However, it only copies the first Range of B2:B34 and pastes it in the first individual sheet and then nothing else is copied in other sheets that are created

Comment: I added in some Debug statements - try running that and take a look at the Immediate pane and see if there's any clue there as to why it's not copying correctly.

Comment: Hey Tim, The code works. i think i just forgot to populate the all ticker analysis sheet to match all the tickers i have put in in the first sheet. Again, thank you very much for you time and effort in helping me figure this out! its is greatly appreciated

Comment: I stand corrected on this, I had my formulas to update manually so after switching them back to updating automatically, the code was working but the reference was still that b2:b34 range

Comment: That would only be the case if `Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)` is failing - I've never seen that happen.

Comment: Hey Tim. Again i appreciate your time and effort, so dont worry about it! i will continue to play with it and see if i can get it to work.